# Can you resave a Django object in same method

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, celery

I have a django function, I am saving the object twice in the same function. As I need the id for the object in my `.delay` (python celery) function. Is it ok to use `.save()` twice, or is it not good practice:

```
def some_function(request, emailname, emailbody):
    email = Email()
    email.name = emailname
    email.save()

    email_id = email.id
    celery_task = send_email.delay(email_id, emailbody)
    
    email.celery_task_id = celery_task.id
    email.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion is to break this function into 2, divide the responsibility. One function, to create an email object and other to send the email. It is necessary as sometimes you might need to perform either of the task like only send email or only create email object, at that time either you need to create another function or put some `if..else` in this function

```
def some_function(request, emailname):
    email = Email()
    email.name = emailname
    email.save()

    return email.id
    
def send_email(email_id, emailbody):
    celery_task = send_email.delay(email_id, emailbody)
    
    email.celery_task_id = celery_task.id
    email.save()
    
    return email
```

The ideal way to create a `class`, object creation goes into `init` and add class method `send_email` for sending emails

Comment: I see how your method may be better practice to split it into two functions. However, can you comment on if there are no technical issues with saving the same instance twice, as I have done in my function?

Comment: Technical issue is - extra database\storage call to save the data, but if it is required then it has to be done.

Answer (score 1):

It's okay to use this way because you need to store email id into celery task and then store back celery id into email object.

You can also resend the email if something went wrong with celery.